# Differences in the capitalization of my name

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, personal-name

In my passport, my name is "SABBIR HASAN" because there was no option to write  in smaller letters. 
I registered on the GRE with my name as "Sabbir Hasan", and I am also writing it this way on the online graduate application form.

Will the difference create any problem?

Comment: All the passports I have seen have the name written in capitals.

Comment: Names are case insensitive.  ALL CAPS is used on paper documents to simplify correct spelling of the name.  When filling paper modules they often require ALL CAPS to avoid unreadable handwritings (and some of these module may even be read by a computer using OCR, and caps might help such programs).

Comment: @Bakuriu: that is not true. E.g., strictly speaking, MacDonald and Macdonald are considered to be two different names.

Comment: Remember that if you're from a country where people use the cyrillic alphabet, you can end with Vičin, Vyčin, Vitchin, Vichin, ... written in place of Вичин. Something like a mistake in capitalization is a minor thing certainly.

Comment: @Bakuriu You might be interested in [falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: @isanae Your link brought up the memory of a student of mine who had XXX written in the first name field of his student's ID card. Is your name XXX?, I asked him. No, I have no first name, my name is just [...] but the system couldn't handle it, so the office put XXX.

Comment: I used to work for someone (in the UK) whose name was 42. He had a sign on his office with "42" on it (which at first glance looked like the room number).

Comment: @Federico French passports write the family name in all caps but the given name(s) with only initial capitals. (I do not know how they handle people with only one name.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should not cause any problems.  People working on graduate admissions typically quite well understand that different systems mess with names in different ways.  Certain types of permutation might cause difficulty, but ALL CAPITALS versus Standard Capitalization is so routine as to likely go entirely unnoticed.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no issue here. Although we traditionally use capital letters for only the initial letters of names<sup>*</sup> and school teachers will tell you it's wrong to do otherwise, the capitalization isn't considered to be part of the spelling. Rather, it's part of the [orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography) of the langauge, which is the set of conventions we use when writing it down. Thus, "Sabbir Hasan", "SABBIR HASAN" and "SaBbIr HaSaN" are all considered to be the same name. The choice of capitalization is more similar to the choice of a font than a choice of spelling.

<sup>*</sup> This is a simplification, as Ronald MacDonald, Ludwig van Beethoven and e e cummings will explain.

Comment: In addition to Ronald and Ludwig van, _c_ might also object (lowercase and italics...) https://www.theverge.com/2018/5/19/17372526/grimes-c-boucher-name-change-elon-musk